# Extracting GTEX Data using GTEX portal API

Tags: python, genetics

I am trying to extract gtex eqtl data from GtexPortal using their API : https://gtexportal.org/home/apiPage

I am looking to extract data for a given SNP ID and tissue location.

I am new to coding and python so I am not sure if what I am doing is right but an example of code I have tried where I give a specific Gene, tissue, and variant ID and am looking to extract the data for these paramaters from the indepndentEqtl data of gtexportal:

```
gencode = "ENSG00000122971"
gene_name = "ALMS1"
tissue = "Heart_Left_Ventricle"

gene_eqtls = requests.get('https://gtexportal.org/api/v2/association/independentEqtl', params = {"gencodeId" : gencode,"tissueSiteDetailId" : tissue, "datasetId" : "gtex_v8", "variantId" : 'rs58235352'})

data = json.loads(gene_eqtls.text)
data
```

```
{'data': [],
 'paging_info': {'numberOfPages': 0,
  'page': 0,
  'maxItem
sPerPage': 250,
  'totalNumberOfItems': 0}}
```

Everything I have been trying has been giving these empty data sets and any help in extracting the data would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

the `gencodeId` needs to be versioned, as per [GTEx API docs](https://gtexportal.org/api/v2/redoc#tag/Static-Association-Endpoints/operation/get_significant_single_tissue_eqtls_api_v2_association_singleTissueEqtl_get) (e.g. `ENSG00000122971.9`, see [ensembl](https://www.ensembl.org/Homo_sapiens/Gene/Summary?g=ENSG00000122971;r=12:120725774-120740008)).

However, I also think there is no output for your example gene in this case anyway. Compare with the following example, which does return some results for me:

```
import requests
import json

json.loads(requests.get('https://gtexportal.org/api/v2/association/independentEqtl', params = {"gencodeId" : "ENSG00000122971.9", "datasetId" : "gtex_v8"}).text)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).